# how to transfer the numbers in a textfile to the next page by importing that textfile in page one using tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to tkinter. I wanted to create an app to add two numbers and pass the result to the next pages. after working on the code and looking into the other posts, I got to this code to do that.

```
import tkinter as tk


class Data:
    def __init__(self):
        self.first_no = tk.IntVar()
        self.second_no = tk.IntVar()
        self.summ = tk.IntVar()


class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.title("Summation App")
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack()

        self.data = Data()

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (PageOne, PageTwo):
            frame = F(container, self.data)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.frames[PageOne].page_button.config(command=self.go_to_page_two)
        self.show_frame(PageOne)

    def go_to_page_two(self):
        self.data.summ.set(self.data.first_no.get() + self.data.second_no.get())
        self.show_frame(PageTwo)

    def show_frame(self, c):
        frame = self.frames[c]
        frame.tkraise()


class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, data):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.data = data

        frame1 = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="This is page one")
        frame1.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

        label1 = tk.Label(frame1, text="First No.")
        label1.grid(row=0, column=0)

        label2 = tk.Label(frame1, text="Second No.")
        label2.grid(row=1, column=0)

        self.entry1 = tk.Entry(frame1, textvariable=data.first_no)
        self.entry1.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.entry2 = tk.Entry(frame1, textvariable=data.second_no)
        self.entry2.grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.page_button = tk.Button(frame1, text="Go to Page Two")
        self.page_button.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)



class PageTwo(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, data):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.data = data

        self.frame2 = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="This is page two")
        self.frame2.pack()

        self.label3 = tk.Label(self.frame2)
        self.label3.pack()

        data.summ.trace('w', lambda a, b, c: self.correct_label())

    def correct_label(self):
        self.label3.config(text=self.data.summ.get())


app = SampleApp()
app.mainloop()
```

Now, I want to extend this code to import a textfile that contains a few numbers, read that and transfer those numbers as a list to the next page. suppose we have a textfile with the name of `Test.txt` which contains a few numbers. in the below code, the results show on the first page. Idon't know how to make connection between my `opentext()` and `new_Var` attribute.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
 
class Data:
 
    def __init__(self):
        self.first_no = tk.IntVar()
        self.second_no = tk.IntVar()
        self.summ = tk.IntVar()
        self.new_Var = tk.StringVar()
 
 
class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.title("Summation App")
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack()
 
        self.data = Data()
 
        self.frames = {}
        for F in (PageOne, PageTwo):
            frame = F(container, self.data)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
 
        self.frames[PageOne].page_button.config(command=self.go_to_page_two)
        self.show_frame(PageOne)
 
    def go_to_page_two(self):
        self.data.summ.set(self.data.first_no.get() + self.data.second_no.get())
        self.show_frame(PageTwo)
 
 
    def show_frame(self, c):
        frame = self.frames[c]
        frame.tkraise()
 
 
class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, data):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.data = data
 
        frame1 = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="This is page one")
        frame1.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
 
        label1 = tk.Label(frame1, text="First No.")
        label1.grid(row=0, column=0)
 
        label2 = tk.Label(frame1, text="Second No.")
        label2.grid(row=1, column=0)
 
        self.entry1 = tk.Entry(frame1, textvariable=data.first_no)
        self.entry1.grid(row=0, column=1)
 
        self.entry2 = tk.Entry(frame1, textvariable=data.second_no)
        self.entry2.grid(row=1, column=1)
 
        self.page_button = tk.Button(frame1, text="Go to Page Two")
        self.page_button.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
 
        label3 = tk.Label(frame1, text="Import the file")
        label3.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10)
 
        def opentext():
            my_file = filedialog.askopenfilenames(initialdir="/pycharm", title="Select your file")
            for T in my_file:
                with open(T, 'r') as infile1:
                    lines = infile1.read()
                    label4.config(text=lines)
                    return lines
 
        self.button1 = tk.Button(frame1, text="Open file(s)", command=opentext)
        self.button1.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
 
        label4 = tk.Label(frame1)
        label4.grid(row=3, column=1)
 
class PageTwo(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, data):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.data = data
 
        self.frame2 = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="This is page two")
        self.frame2.pack()
 
        self.label5 = tk.Label(self.frame2)
        self.label5.pack()
 
        self.label6 = tk.Label(self.frame2)
        self.label6.pack()
 
        # When someone changes summ, I need to update the label
        data.summ.trace('w', lambda a, b, c: self.correct_label())
 
    def correct_label(self):
        self.label5.config(text=self.data.summ.get())
        self.label6.config(text=self.data.new_Var)
 
 
app = SampleApp()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you looked at all of the related questions and answers here? https://stackoverflow.com/a/7557028/7432

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Actually, yes. I read almost all your post regarding the classes. But I am confused which way is better. I am trying to have a sample code to see how I can import a file and pass to other windows or pages and use it whenever I need that.
I am confused where to use opentext() function and where I have to update my code.

Comment: You can create another attribute in `Data` class and do the same on it just like what you do on `Data.summ`.

Comment: @acw1668 how about the opentext() function? should I move it into the SampleApp class?

Comment: I don't understand why you need to move `opentext()` to `SampleApp` since it is part of `PageOne`.

Comment: I am doing that, but it is not working. I am so confused about this.

Comment: You better update your question with what you have tried and state clearly *what is not working*.

Comment: thanks. it is updated. my problem is that I dont know how to make the connection between my new_Var and the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update `Data.new_Var` inside `opentext()` and link this variable to `PageTwo.label6` using `textvariable` option:

```py
class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, data):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.data = data
        ...
        def opentext():
            # why do you use askopenfilenames() instead of askopenfilename()???
            my_file = filedialog.askopenfilenames(initialdir="/pycharm", title="Select your file")
            for T in my_file:
                with open(T, 'r') as infile1:
                    lines = infile1.read()
                    label4.config(text=lines)
                    self.data.new_Var.set(lines) # update Data.new_Var
                    return lines
        ...

class PageTwo(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, data):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.data = data
        ...
        self.label6 = tk.Label(self.frame2, textvariable=self.data.new_Var)
        self.label6.pack()
        ...
```

Note that you don't need to update `self.label6` inside `correct_label()`.

Comment: Oh thank you very much you saved me. the reason I used askopenfilenames() instead of askopenfilename() was to be able to open multiple files.