# Using the passed variables in another windows (tkinter)

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I wanted to create an app to calculate the total number of grids, by getting the number of grids in X,Y, and Z directions. I also want to use the result to be moved in the next windows. I found this post below, and I used it as my code basis.

[how to transfer the numbers in a textfile to the next page by importing that textfile in page one using tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71120035/how-to-transfer-the-numbers-in-a-textfile-to-the-next-page-by-importing-that-tex)

I could write my code to calculate the total grids and show it in the next window.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Data:
    def __init__(self):
        self.nx = tk.IntVar()
        self.ny = tk.IntVar()
        self.nz = tk.IntVar()
        self.Tot_grids = tk.IntVar()
        self.A = tk.IntVar()

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.title("Test app")
        self.geometry("400x400")

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack()

        self.data = Data()

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (PageOne, PageTwo):
            frame = F(container, self.data)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.frames[PageOne].button4_P1.config(command=self.go_to_page_two)
        self.show_frame(PageOne)

    def go_to_page_two(self):
        self.show_frame(PageTwo)

    def show_frame(self, c):
        frame = self.frames[c]
        frame.tkraise()

class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, data):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.data = data

        self.frame_1 = tk.Frame(self)
        self.frame_1.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.label_1 = tk.Label(self.frame_1, text="nx")
        self.label_1.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.entry_1 = tk.Entry(self.frame_1, textvariable=data.nx)
        self.entry_1.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.label_2 = tk.Label(self.frame_1, text="ny")
        self.label_2.grid(row=1, column=0)

        self.entry_2 = tk.Entry(self.frame_1, textvariable=data.ny)
        self.entry_2.grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.label_3 = tk.Label(self.frame_1, text="nz")
        self.label_3.grid(row=2, column=0)

        self.entry_3 = tk.Entry(self.frame_1, textvariable=data.nz)
        self.entry_3.grid(row=2, column=1)

        def total_grids():
            nt = data.nx.get() * data.ny.get() * data.nz.get()
            self.label_4.config(text=str(nt))
            data.Tot_grids.set(nt)

        self.button1 = tk.Button(self.frame_1, text="Calculate", command=total_grids)
        self.button1.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2)

        self.button4_P1 = tk.Button(self.frame_1, text="Continue")
        self.button4_P1.grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=4, pady=5)

        self.label_4 = tk.Label(self.frame_1)
        self.label_4.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=2)

class PageTwo(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, data):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.data = data

        self.frame2 = tk.Frame(self)
        self.frame2.pack()

        self.label_5 = tk.Label(self.frame2, textvariable=self.data.Tot_grids)
        self.label_5.pack()

app = SampleApp()
app.mainloop()
```

But, I don't know how to use it for further calculations. assume I want to do a simple calculation and add the passed variable by `100`. I added a few lines to do that in class `PageTwo`, but it gives me an error.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Data:
    def __init__(self):
        self.nx = tk.IntVar()
        self.ny = tk.IntVar()
        self.nz = tk.IntVar()
        self.Tot_grids = tk.IntVar()
        self.A = tk.IntVar()

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.title("Test app")
        self.geometry("400x400")

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack()

        self.data = Data()

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (PageOne, PageTwo):
            frame = F(container, self.data)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.frames[PageOne].button4_P1.config(command=self.go_to_page_two)
        self.show_frame(PageOne)

    def go_to_page_two(self):
        self.show_frame(PageTwo)

    def show_frame(self, c):
        frame = self.frames[c]
        frame.tkraise()

class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, data):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.data = data

        self.frame_1 = tk.Frame(self)
        self.frame_1.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.label_1 = tk.Label(self.frame_1, text="nx")
        self.label_1.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.entry_1 = tk.Entry(self.frame_1, textvariable=data.nx)
        self.entry_1.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.label_2 = tk.Label(self.frame_1, text="ny")
        self.label_2.grid(row=1, column=0)

        self.entry_2 = tk.Entry(self.frame_1, textvariable=data.ny)
        self.entry_2.grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.label_3 = tk.Label(self.frame_1, text="nz")
        self.label_3.grid(row=2, column=0)

        self.entry_3 = tk.Entry(self.frame_1, textvariable=data.nz)
        self.entry_3.grid(row=2, column=1)

        def total_grids():
            nt = data.nx.get() * data.ny.get() * data.nz.get()
            self.label_4.config(text=str(nt))
            data.Tot_grids.set(nt)

        self.button1 = tk.Button(self.frame_1, text="Calculate", command=total_grids)
        self.button1.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2)

        self.button4_P1 = tk.Button(self.frame_1, text="Continue")
        self.button4_P1.grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=4, pady=5)

        self.label_4 = tk.Label(self.frame_1)
        self.label_4.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=2)

class PageTwo(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, data):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.data = data

        self.frame2 = tk.Frame(self)
        self.frame2.pack()

        self.label_5 = tk.Label(self.frame2, textvariable=self.data.Tot_grids)
        self.label_5.pack()

        self.data.A = self.data.Tot_grids + 100

        self.label_6 = tk.Label(self.frame2, textvariable=self.data.A)
        self.label_6.pack()

app = SampleApp()
app.mainloop()
```

I also have this question, do we really need to use `self` before every label, entry fields, or button. I removed some of them, and the code was working for my code. Does removing them cause problems later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can us tkinter variable `.trace()` to update `Data.A` whenever `Data.tot_grids` is updated:

```py
class PageTwo(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, data):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.data = data

        self.frame2 = tk.Frame(self)
        self.frame2.pack()

        self.label_5 = tk.Label(self.frame2, textvariable=self.data.Tot_grids)
        self.label_5.pack()

        self.label_6 = tk.Label(self.frame2, textvariable=self.data.A)
        self.label_6.pack()

        # call on_grids_updated() whenever Data.Tot_grids is updated
        self.data.Tot_grids.trace_add('write', self.on_grids_updated)

    def on_grids_updated(self, *args):
        self.data.A.set(self.data.Tot_grids.get() + 100)
```

For question on using `self`, if the variable will be accessed in other class methods, then you need to prefix it with `self.` to make it an instance variable, otherwise the prefix is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. just a question. It seems the variable gets its value from `Label_5` in PageTwo and not the variable in PageOne. because when I deleted         
`self.label_5 = tk.Label(self.frame2, textvariable=self.data.Tot_grids)

  self.label_5.pack()`, the code doesnt work. so, how we can dirrectly relates that to PageOne calss?

Comment: @Luke20 What do you mean by "the code doesnt work" after deleting `self.label_5`? I still get the correct result in `self.label_6`.

Comment: you are right. it was my mistake. May I ask what should I do when the variable passing from PageOne to PageTwo is a list of numbers? because there is no variable to define that. and StringVar, and IntVar or DoubleVar cannot do that?

Comment: Try using `Variable`.

Comment: Sorry, didn't quite understand. what is `Variable`? could you please let me know what should I exactly look for on the net?

Comment: `Variable` is the base class of `StringVar`, `IntVar`, etc.